# java create string array from multiple arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

i have multiple arraylist like this:

```
arraylist
arrayList.add(product1);
arrayList.add(product2);
arrayList.add(product3);
arrayList.add(product4);
.
.
.
.
arrayList.add(productn);


arraylist2
arrayList2.add(name1);
arrayList2.add(name2);
arrayList2.add(name3);
arrayList2.add(name4);
.
.
.
arrayList2.add(namen);


  arraylist3
arrayList3.add(id1);
arrayList3.add(id2);
arrayList3.add(id3);
arrayList3.add(id4);
.
.
.
arrayList3.add(idn);
```

i want to create string of array combine of arraylists above
with index of string in arraylist

so something like this

```
string[1] = {product1,name1,id1 }
string[2] = {product2,name2,id2 }
.
.
.
string[n] = {productn,namen,idn }
```

any idea how to do it?
sorry before 
and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class and then an array of instances/objects of that class. Here's an example,

```
public class Product{
    String name;
    String id;
    public Product(String name, String id){ //constructor for the object
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then in your main method, create an array of type `Product` and added instances of `Product` to the array,

```
Product[] products = new Product[10];
products[0] = new Product("cheese", "0");
System.out.println(products[0].name + " " + products[0].id);
```

You can adjust to your liking, for example you can edit the `Product` class by adding more instance fields other than `name` and `id`, resize the array, change the array to an arraylist, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
int size = 10;
List<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> arr3 = new ArrayList<>();
String[] string = new String[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    string[i] = arr1.get(i) + arr2.get(i) + arr3.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through them in one loop and create an object with it.

we need to create a class

```
// The data type will change based on the data type you have them as

public class MyObject {
   private Product product;
   private Name name; 
   private Id id; 

   public MyObject(Product p, Name n, Id i) {
       product = p;
       name = n;
       id = i;
   }
   // All Getters & toString()
}
```

Now for the loop :

```
List< MyObject> myList = new ArrayList < MyObject >();
for ( int i=0 ; i < arrayList || i < arrayList2 || i < arrayList3 ) {
     myList.add(new MyObject(arrayList.get(i),arrayList2.get(i),arrayList3.get(i)))
}
```

Note you can override the toString method in you class to get the output in the way you want.
EG:

```
public String toString() { 
    return "Name: '" + this.name + "', ID: '" + this.id + "', Product: '" + this.product + "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)  { 
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("product1");
    arrayList.add("product2");
    arrayList.add("product3");
    List<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList2.add("name1");
    arrayList2.add("name2");
    arrayList2.add("name3");
    List<String> arrayList3 = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList3.add("id1");
    arrayList3.add("id2");
    arrayList3.add("id3");

    int n = arrayList.size();
    List<String[]> productlist = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i< n;i++){
        productlist.add(new String[]{arrayList.get(i),arrayList2.get(i),arrayList3.get(i)});
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(productlist.get(i)));
    }
}
```